# How to get instance from memory address in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I am debugging a production site and I would like to get an instance from an address. Here an instance of the class `Map` that would like to get into my console. Is this something possible?

[image]